# different answers with boolean questions

Tags: java

Whenever i place my return statements in different places, it makes different outcomes, can anyone explain why?

`str` will hold any given value as long as it returns the right outcome.

```
fizzString("fooo") → "Fizz"
fizzString("b") → "Buzz"
fizzString("fb") → "FizzBuzz"

public String fizzString(String str) {
    boolean fizz = str.charAt(0) == 'f';
    boolean buzz = str.charAt(str.length() - 1) == 'b';

    if (fizz && buzz) return "FizzBuzz";
    if (fizz) return "Fizz";
    if (buzz) return "Buzz";

    return str;
}
```

different from

```
public String fizzString(String str) {
    boolean fizz = str.charAt(0) == 'f';
    boolean buzz = str.charAt(str.length() - 1) == 'b';


    if (fizz) return "Fizz";
    if (buzz) return "Buzz";
    if (fizz && buzz) return "FizzBuzz";

    return str;
}
```

Comment: what is the str parameter holding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return statement will terminate the process and leave the method. If you put

```
if (fizz && buzz) return "FizzBuzz";
```

at the end of the method, it can never be reached, because if both `fizz` and `buzz` are `true`, the first statement will already be true and "Fizz" will be returned. The two following statements will not even be evaluated.

What you want is the first version - you should first check whether both are true and then whether only one is true. In the second case, the last statment is actually unreachable and that should never happen in your code.

If you want the statements to be interchangable, you can change them to the following:

```
if ( fizz &&  buzz) return "FizzBuzz";
if ( fizz && !buzz) return "Fizz";
if (!fizz &&  buzz) return "Buzz";
```

Answer (score 0):

Return statement will be executed only once per method. So whenever your 'if' statement is true your method will return the particular return statement and exit the code. In this example the output depends upon the value that the str parameter holds.

Answer (score 0):

In the first code snipet

```
if (fizz && buzz) return "FizzBuzz";
 if (fizz) return "Fizz";
 if (buzz) return "Buzz";
```

with first if you check if both fizz and buzz is true. And if either of them is false this if doesn`t execute and skipped. And then second and first ifs check fizz and buzz separately and if the second (fizz) condition is true "Fizz" will be returned. Otherwise condition if buzz is true will be checked.
In the second code snipet

```
if (fizz) return "Fizz";
 if (buzz) return "Buzz";
if (fizz && buzz) return "FizzBuzz";
```

the last condition (fizz && buzz) will never be executed, as before it there fizz or buzz conditions which can be true and method returns. 
If you need to check condition (fizz && buzz) both true better use first code snippet.
Or you can refactor the code, for example:

```
public String fizzString(String str) {
   boolean fizz = str.charAt(0) == 'f';
   boolean buzz = str.charAt(str.length() - 1) == 'b';

  String res = str;
  if (fizz && buzz) res = "FizzBuzz";
  if (fizz) res = "Fizz";
  if (buzz) res = "Buzz";

  return str;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

this snippet1

```
if (fizz && buzz)
    return "FizzBuzz";
if (fizz)
    return "Fizz";
if (buzz)
    return "Buzz";
```

and this snippet2

```
if (fizz)
    return "Fizz";
if (buzz)
    return "Buzz";
if (fizz && buzz)
    return "FizzBuzz";
```

are checking different condition in different order... the result can not be the same since the logic is different

example:

in the snippet2 you return "Fizz" when the parameter begin with f, and the value of the variable buzz doenst care anymore....

```
    if (fizz)
        return "Fizz";
```

but in snippet1 both conditions must be met! start with ***f*** and end with ***b***

Comment: The first 2/3rds of your answer is just "here is your code + some line breaks"